# Google Sheets Merge many ranges into a single range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, flatten

There's this formula that merges two ranges:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN({IF(COUNTIFS( C3:C14 ; C3:C14 ;ROW(C3:C14);"<="&ROW(C3:C14))=1;C3:C14;""); D3:D14});FLATTEN({IF(COUNTIFS( C3:C14 ; C3:C14 ;ROW(C3:C14);"<="&ROW(C3:C14))=1;C3:C14;""); D3:D14})<>""));1;TRUE)
```

Which Merges the ranges (`C3:C14` and `D3:D14`) into a single column, then it filters blank cells, removes duplicates and then sorts values in ascending order.

Is there an easier/lighter way to merge many ranges into a single range while ignoring blanks and duplicates? In my case I need to merge from `C3` to `H14` which makes 6 columns. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(flatten(C3:E14)),1,1)
```

[image]

to also remove the trailing empty cell please use

```
=FILTER(SORT(UNIQUE(flatten(C3:E14)),1,1), 
        SORT(UNIQUE(flatten(C3:E14)),1,1)<>"")
```

Comment: *"from Col4 to Col6 all values seem to be ignored"*. They are not ignored. You mentioned *"removes duplicates"* Those are duplicates. Take another look or try it in your data. If still in trouble please share some data and expected results

Comment: You have to take into account your locale. Try `=SORT(UNIQUE(flatten(C3:E14));1;1)`

Comment: Found the problem, since I just copied and pasted your formula (C3:E14) the last 3 columns (F3:H14) were not included X) In my defense is well past midnight here.

Thank you very mcuh for the help. Your formula really made things simpler.

Comment: Sorry. The formula works as expected. Please share a test sheet with dummy data and expected results.

Comment: *"Found the problem..."*. I know the feeling. I make sleep deprivation slip-ups all the time. :)

Comment: Please also notice that my formula will leave a trailing empty cell in the end. Do you also want that removed?

Comment: What formula would be needed to remove the empty cell?